# I want my list to be appended with 8 arrays

Tags: arrays, list, append, python-3.5

So i will explain the purpose behind the code design. I wish to make a list of length 8 with each iterable containing an array of length 80000. The code intent is to run n=0, then jump into the for loop iterating over length 80000, then to append the array into my previously defined list. This process will continue for n--> 8. so the list will hopefully be 8 wide and 80000 deep. I am brushing off my python dust so I cannot seem to see my error, I'm sure it's quite simple, thank you in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp
import random as rand

# grabs function ignoring constants and inputs into 2 column array
# with all t_values as well as the v(t) output

# lets add in constants
# let's write time constants in terms of us (microseconds)
theta = .1
T_clk = .004
theta = (theta / T_clk)
range_of_time = 80000


def v(tau):
    all_pulses = []
    start_times = list(range(20, 100, 10))
    pulses = np.zeros(range_of_time)

    for n in range(8):

        for ab in range(range_of_time):
            t = ab * T_clk
            pulses[ab] = (exp(-(t-start_times[n]))/tau - exp(-(t - start_times[n]))/theta)
        all_pulses.append(pulses)
    return all_pulses

print(v(55.7)[7])
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow the instruction for asking a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic